# asynctask android how to get json response from php backend

Tags: android

how we can show the php response from android

```
public class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        String name="",path="";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            name=product_Image_name;
            path=getPath(originalUri);
            Log.d("path",path+"");
            Log.d("name",name+"");
            Log.d("uploadurl",upload_url+"");


        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try{

                new MultipartUploadRequest(MainActivity.this,name,upload_url)
                        .setMethod("POST")
                        .addFileToUpload(path,"uploadedfile")
                        .addParameter("name",name)
                        .setMaxRetries(2)
                        .startUpload();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

          clearData();


        }

    }
```

**Below is my php backend**

```
<?php 

$target_path="./uploadImage/";
$target_path=$target_path.basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$target_path)){

echo "upladed Sucessfuly";

}
else{

    echo "upladed error !";
}

?>
```

Comment: I do not see a response? Where is it?

Comment: Please put all code in your code block.

Comment: Is this from the android upload service api?  If so then a response is obtained from the `UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver` to receive upload service events.